# Change locale before compiling in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm running my Ubuntu install in the swedish language so when I compile my c++ program thru emacs it spits out the warnings in swedish. That makes it harder to search for solutions to problem and to ask questions here on Stack Overflow. Therefor I ask how I can make Emacs change the LANG-parameter before executing `make -k`. It seems like it should'nt be that hard. But I could'nt figure it out by googleing.

## Solution

Based om sepp2k:s answer this is what I added to my .emacs file:

```
; Change compile-command
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
  (lambda ()
    (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command) "LANG=C make -k")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `LANG=C make -k` as your compilation command. This will invoke `make` with `LANG` set to `C`.

Comment: Oh, that seems resonable... Now I just have to google how to change the compilation command i Emacs ;) Thanks alot!

Comment: If it's GNU make I believe `export LANG` after `LANG=C` in the Makefile should work as well.

Comment: oh, ok. Well it is. So that's another. sepp2k:s solution would work for every project right of the box, but your would work indepent of where I compile it from... So, I guess it depends on priorities.